# Unknown Part For '78 Lincoln

Tags: electrical, ford, part-identification, lincoln, continental

I recently changed the Ignition Control Module on my 1978 Lincoln Continental. This part was mounted onto the ICM and plugs directly into it. I have gone to the Lincoln/Ford dealership, visited multiple auto part stores, and searched everywhere online, but I cannot figure out what the name of this part is called or it’s purpose. If anyone is familiar with older Lincoln’s, I would greatly appreciate it if you could tell me what this part is and where I can find a replacement. Currently, the car is running and driving without it, but I’d still like to replace it as it must have some importance. The numbers on the part in question are D8AE-12A265-BA. Below those numbers on a separate line are 75-566 (not sure if that is supposed to be a part of the first set of numbers).

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Is that black protrusion a fitting for a tube?

Comment: @jwh20 I believe so, however, I am not certain. No tube was connected to that part when I bought the car (which doesn’t mean one shouldn’t be there).

Comment: My thought is that it's some sort of air valve.  It opens up and lets air in or out from that tube to the outside air.

Comment: You may be right. I need the exact name or part # to find a replacement. It has a faint part number on it but I’ve tried looking all over the internet and still can’t find that part.

Comment: It's going to be really tough to find such a part for such an old model as this.  If you really need it you might try some local junk yards.  Chances are good that it was used on multiple Ford models from that vintage.

Comment: How do you know this one is bad?

Comment: Yes I know. It just doesn’t make sense because I can find extensive information about the ICM and the wiring of my Lincoln, but I can’t find a part that connects to 1 of the 3 connectors on my ICM. There’s a single connector on the ICM specifically and solely for this part, so it must be important?

Comment: The 2 wires that were attached to it broke off. I’d solder them back on, but I don’t know which one went where. I don’t want to guess and then mess up something in the ICM. I’d rather just replace it but it’s looking pretty hopeless so far.

Comment: I'd bet it doesn't matter which wire goes on which terminal. At worst, it's a 50/50 shot, right?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I’d rather not spend another $70 for a new ICM again....

Comment: Point taken. :o)

Comment: Might not be useful, but to my eyeballs the top connector in the last picture looks copper colored, whereas the bottom one looks silver colored. Were they by any chance color coded, and are the broken spade connectors still stuck together? You might be able to see which ones broke off of where based on color or the break pattern.

Comment: It looks like some sort of vacuum solenoid, but I have no clue of its purpose within the system.  Best bet is to find an Electrical / Vacuum Troubleshooting Manual (EVTM) for that make and model and search for that part.  Cruise control?  Emissions?

Comment: @zipzit I have a Haynes manual for these model cars, but it doesn’t show the electrical diagram for ‘78 Lincolns (even though the book is for 1970 thru 2010). Cruise control works currently without this part, so it probably isn’t for that. It’s most likely for emissions. The car runs fine, but it’s horrendous on gas. This is my first “vintage” car, so I’m not sure if the terrible gas mileage is normal.

Comment: @JakeScervino, we had an '83 Continental with a 5.0 v8, and it usually got about 17 mpg. I'd guess yours would be a little less, what with the larger engine, probably around 12 - 14 mpg.

Comment: @the_storyteller Yeah, that sounds about right. Not complaining though.... I absolutely love the car regardless. They sure don't make them like they used to.